# Turn on Harmony mode -- how do I do that in order to run ReactJS v0.13?

Tags: gruntjs, gulp, reactjs, ecmascript-harmony

I am following [this comment](https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/a6e220b7097eb3c79ab7#comment-1336981) where I am told to turn on harmony mode in order to use destructing assignments for ReactJS v0.13.

I have googled around and cannot find a good answer on how to turn this on.

If turning on Harmony mode is a bad idea, what is the highest version for ReactJS I must use instead?

**UPDATE**
development workflow will either use grunt or gulp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a single answer to your question as it depends on your development build workflow.

If you were using `node-jsx` npm package for example:

```
require('node-jsx').install({harmony: true});
```

If you used the command line compiler:

```
JSX filename -harmony
```

There is a solution for webpack, [grunt](https://github.com/ericclemmons/grunt-react#optionsharmony), etc.

WebPack for example uses a loader flag:

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  entry: './main.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js'       
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'jsx-loader?harmony' }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    // you can now require('file') instead of require('file.jsx')
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.json', '.jsx'] 
  }
};
```

There's an [option for gulp](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-react) that works like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var react = require('gulp-react');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp.src('template.jsx')
        .pipe(react({harmony: true}))  // enable harmony features
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Comment: Thank you. The team I work with has yet to decide what to use, but we are deciding between gulp or grunt.

Comment: I've added a few more links. Beyond that ... I'd just recommending searching for `jsx harmony` and the build system you want to use. There are a few options for each.

Answer (score 0):

If you use cdn versions of the react and jsx libraries from v0.11 and above

e.g.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.0-beta.1/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.0-beta.1/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
```

Just change the script tag accordingly to have harmony mode by **adding ;harmony=true**

```
<script type="text/jsx;harmony=true">
/** @jsx React.DOM */
    var APP = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <BButton className="btn-primary" href="javascript:alert('hello');" ><BHeart /> React</BButton> // and so on..
```

Credit to [Facebook docs on v0.11](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/07/17/react-v0.11.html)